# Refetching with Apollo updates all instance of that query, even with different params

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have 2 queries that look like this:

```
const Basket = ({children}) => <Query
    query={MY_QUERY}
    variables={{ list: 'BASKET' }}>
    {children}
</Query>

const Bin = ({children}) => <Query
    query={MY_QUERY}
    variables={{ list: 'BIN' }}>
    {children}
</Query>
```

Now, I use them like this:

```
<Basket>
    {({ data, loading, error, refetch }) => {
        return loading ? (
            <div>Loading</div>
        ) : error ? (
            <div>Error</div>
        ) : (
            <div>
                <MyTable data={data} />
                <button onClick={() => refetch()}>refetch</button>
            </div>
        );
    }}
</Basket>

<Bin>
    {({ data, loading, error, refetch }) => {
        return loading ? (
            <div>Loading</div>
        ) : error ? (
            <div>Error</div>
        ) : (
            <div>
                <MyTable data={data} />
                <button onClick={() => refetch()}>refetch</button>
            </div>
        );
    }}
</Bin>
```

Now here is the problem:

If I press the button to re-fetch the contents of basket, that data will appear not only in `<Basket>` but also in `<Bin>`!

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your queries have the same name Apollo cache won't know the data being returned is different - so it will update both Components.

If changing this doesn't help please post your query code for each query